# Angular ng-switch method hiding html elements after page rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular ng-switch method works but , before fired ng-switch , while first loading of webpage htmls are visible for a second and after unvisible (sometimes not doing maybe it is about cookies) , it is looking bad for user experiance and it is not look like professional .

**Shortly;**
Angular hide elements after page rendered

i think , Users never see this situation.

How can i hide this situation ?

***Solution for codeMirror issue***;
According to answers ng-cloak is the true answer of this issue but if you use codeMirror code editor , it is crashing with ng-cloak , In order to solve this problem you should use this module ;
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Put this in your css file:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Then put ng-cloak attribute on the element that you want to be hidden temporarily when the page load. When angular finishes all the binding, it will remove ng-cloak

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

Comment: Okay but if i add ng-cloak  my codeMirror javascript functions not working properly :( Maybe , should i add to script document.ready function

Comment: Now ,if i add document.ready function to top of script textareas are visible but codeMirror code editor still not working